# setTimeout() not working in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

New to AngularJSs.  Wondering why `setTimeout` is not working. Is it true that it doe snot work with AngularJS?

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/0afonb9g/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model='form'  ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions'></select>
</div>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {

    //$scope.typeOptions = [];
    alert("hi23");
    $timeout(function() {
        alert("hi");
        $scope.typeOptions =
    [
    { name: 'Feature', value: 'feature' }, 
    { name: 'Bug', value: 'bug' }, 
    { name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement' }
    ]; 
     $scope.form =  $scope.typeOptions[1].value;                     
    }, 3000);


}
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to inject `$timeout`. Observe the following change

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) { 
    ....
}
```

See the [`$timeout` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) for more information

---

Furthermore, this style of declaring controllers is not recommended. I would encourage re-fractoring to the following...

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    .... 
}]);
```

Comment: In addition to what sal niro said, you need to initiate your controller.

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

Comment: Thanks guys!  Here is the link to a working version with the style you recommended:  http://jsfiddle.net/m4ozztsk/

Comment: Here's a good article on use of `$timeout` and `$interval` http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/timeout-interval.html

Answer (score 4):

Angular has a list of watchers, which is all the variables and objects that bind the view with its model. Angular keeps listening for events that change any of these and starts a digest cycle to update the DOM with the new values.

When you use setTimeout, it runs asynchronously and all the code inside setTimeout is not watched by Angular, even though it might be changing one of the Angular scope values.

So you can either use $timeout as suggested above or you can wrap your setTimeout code within $scope.$apply, which tells Angular to watch for it also.

This is also a good practice for any external Jquery libraries you may be using within your Angular app. Although recommended way is to use Angular wrappers for such libraries.